# How to calculate correlation coefficient for data with repeated values in one variable?

Tags: correlation

I want to measure the strength of the linear relationship between gene expression and a phenotypic variable for a number of species. However, I only have gene expression values at the species level, not for each individual, meaning the expression values are repeated. The plot below shows some representative (fake) data for three species.

Some more background: the phenotypic variable we're measuring is the response to an antibody-targeted compound, and the antibody should be binding to a specific gene product. We therefore want to measure whether the expression of that gene in a species is correlated with the observed effect of the compound, since that will tell us the degree to which the targeting of the compound by the antibody matters.

My questions are:

1. Is a Pearson correlation appropriate for data like this with many repeated values? If not, why exactly? I think the answer is no but I can't quite say why.
2. If Pearson correlation is not appropriate, what is one other analysis that could measure the strength of the linear relationship between the two variables that takes into account the repeated values?

[image]

Comment: You will need to step back from saying "I want to quantify association" (which is very vague and may be interpreted in multiple ways) to thinking about the underlying problem that this "correlation" is supposed to solve. There's multiple potential things that might be "the right thing" for your particular needs (NB I don't know your area). Some of them may be correlations, some may be other things. It's very easy for us to fall into giving a great solution to entirely the wrong problem. It's important to understand the problem we should be solving and for that vagueness won't do.

Comment: @Glen_b Thank you. I tried to include more detail, and I'm happy to include even more if it's needed. At the heart of it I really want to know i) why is Pearson correlation wrong for this, and ii) what's an example of any other analysis that will measure a similar linear relationship while taking into account the repeated values. I'm happy being pointed toward any solution that's appropriate (but I know less specific questions like that can be annoying).

Comment: Thanks. You say "since that will tell us the degree to which the targeting of the compound by the antibody matters" ... I don't think correlation generally tells you how much something matters (at least not directly). It seems to you skipped the very part I'd seek details about (why correlation matters operationally, so I can see *which* correlation you might want). What would "matters" mean in a practical sense here?